# How to represent this as a Network?

Tags: python, graph, substring

I want to make a visualization that shows how many words a substring belongs to. Some substrings may belong to the same set of words. For example, the substrings `tion` and `ten` are both substrings of the words `detention` and `attention`.

I thought about a tree representation but in my actual program there are hundreds of these parent to child relationships, and since two or three parents may have the same child it can get really complicated. Therefore, I think a network would work.

Here's the code that sets it up.

```
from collections import defaultdict

words = ['mention', 'detention', 'attention', 'iteraction', 'interception', 'solution', 'iteraction',
     'reiteration', 'determination', 'tension', 'tentative', 'intention', 'solution',
     'tentative', 'concatenation', 'alternative', 'bitter', 'asterisk']

substring_dict = defaultdict(list)
ter = 'ter'
tion = 'tion'
ten = 'ten'

for entry in words:
    if ter in entry:
        substring_dict[ter].append(entry)
    if tion in entry:
        substring_dict[tion].append(entry)
    if ten in entry:
        substring_dict[ten].append(entry)
```

`substring_dict` is a dictionary of lists where the key is the substring and the value is the list of words that the substring belongs to.

How do I represent this visually? I was thinking I could color code the nodes as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/) to visualize your graph.

Let's first make a small change in your pre-processing:

```
words = ['mention', 'detention', 'attention', 'iteraction', 'interception', 'solution', 'iteraction','reiteration', 'determination', 'tension', 'tentative', 'intention', 'solution', 'tentative', 'concatenation', 'alternative', 'bitter', 'asterisk']

subs = ['ter','tion','ten']
edges = []

for word in words:
    for sub in subs:
        if sub in word:
            edges.append( (word, sub) )

print edges[0:6]

# prints [('mention', 'tion'), ('detention', 'tion'), ('detention', 'ten'), ('attention', 'tion'), ('attention', 'ten'), ('iteraction', 'ter')]
```

Let's start plotting:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

g = nx.Graph()
g.add_nodes_from(subs)
g.add_nodes_from(words)
g.add_edges_from(edges)
pos=nx.spring_layout(g)

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(g, pos,
                       nodelist=subs,
                       node_color='r',
                       node_size=1000,
                       alpha=0.8)

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(g, pos,
                       nodelist=words,
                       node_color='b',
                       node_size=1000,
                       alpha=0.8)

nx.draw_networkx_edges(g, pos, width=1.0, alpha=0.5)

nx.draw_networkx_labels(g, pos, dict(zip(subs,subs)) )
nx.draw_networkx_labels(g, pos, dict(zip(words,words)) )
```

It produces:[image]

**Notes:**

1. You might want to work on placement of the nodes, now we are using `nx.spring_layout` which should be changed.
2. Play with the sizes of the nodes so that labels do not extend outside.

Comment: thanks, this is exactly what I wanted. let me see if I can reproduce this in my actual program (the one with hundreds of these parent to child relationship). let me get back to you if I get stuck.

Comment: You are welcome. I am sure it will be way cooler if you manage to give a more appropriate layout. For example red nodes in the middle as a circle , and blue nodes as a bigger outer circle, maybe..